# Use multiple arguments stored in one variable in a command, in fish shell

Tags: fish

I want to pass a bunch of parameters, stored in a variable, to a built in command, in a fish shell script. For example, like this:

```
set params "-h -d 1"
du $params
```

I was hoping the above would be equivalent to

```
du -h -d 1
```

But, it is not. It results in an error: "du: illegal option --"

It does work if I just set `params` to `-h` or to `-d 1` but not both.

The one workaround I found is to do

```
eval du $params
```

but this seems...wrong, excessive. Any cleaner way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just drop the quotes.

The reason something like this works in POSIX shells (like bash) is because of "[word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)". When you use an unquoted variable, the value is substituted and then split along the characters in the IFS variable (typically tab, newline and space).

In fish, just use an array to separate the elements in the first place. And as it happens, the only change needed is to remove the quotes:

```
set params -h -d 1
du $params
```

Comment: What I am really doing is

    `set param (cat /tmp/p)`

How do I drop the quotes when I'm reading the params from a file. They do not have quotes in the file.

Comment: Fish _does_ perform splitting on command substitutions (but not variable expansion), but only on newlines. So either split it explicitly (with e.g. `(string split " " < /tmp/p)`) or change the file to use newlines instead - which will also work in POSIX shells, since they split on newlines as well.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks!